# How to get number of results from query_posts?

Tags: wordpress

I'm printing posts and I want to get number of results, how can I do that?

This is part of my code:

```
if (have_posts()) : 

    $args = array(
        'showposts' => '5',
        'paged' => $paged
    );


    $thePosts = query_posts($args);
...
```

Thank's for help

Comment: Do you want to say your search has _______ results? If not please add more to your question

Comment: @RyanB - I want to print for example: 5 results found

Comment: look at: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/display-search-term-and-result-count-in-wordpress/

Comment: Can you take your solution, make it an answer, and accept it? That way, it can help others in the future who find this question.

Comment: sure, hopefuly it doesn't get marked as a comment by mods

Answer (score 50, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
if (have_posts()) : 

        $args = array(
            'showposts' => '5',
            'paged' => $paged
        );


        $thePosts = query_posts($args);


         global $wp_query; 
         echo $wp_query->found_posts;
    ...
```

Comment: You can only do $thePosts->found_posts; to get the count! Thank you for your answer! It showed me how to do it ^^

Answer (score 7):

To display the number of results of a search, use:

```
Search Result for 

<?php 
/* Search Count */ 
$allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); 
$key = wp_specialchars($s, 1);
$count = $allsearch->post_count; _e('');
 _e('<span class="search-terms">'); 
echo $key; _e('</span>'); 
_e(' &mdash; '); 
echo $count . ' ';
 _e('articles');
 wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

This was taken from: [WP Beginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/display-search-term-and-result-count-in-wordpress/).

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer is

```
 if (have_posts()) : 

    $args = array(
        'showposts' => '5',
        'paged' => $paged
    );


    $thePosts = query_posts($args);



     echo $thePosts ->found_posts;
...
```

Comment: I have edited the approved answer http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11096000/revisions to be better, but then the edit was not approved hence this other attempt.

Answer (score 6):

This will give you the results: Showing results 11-20 of 46, for instance.

```
  $args = array(
    'cat'=> $cat,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged,
    's'=> $s
  );
  query_posts($args);

  $startpost=1;
  $startpost=10*($paged - 1)+1;
  $endpost = (10*$paged < $wp_query->found_posts ? 10*$paged : $wp_query->found_posts);
        ?>
  <h2 class="displayResult">Showing results <?php echo $startpost; ?> - <?php echo $endpost; ?> of <?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?></h2>
```

If this is not a search page, simply remove the line `"'s'=> $s"`.

If you do need it, make sure you declare the variable as `$_GET['s']` above.

Answer (score 2):

Easy. To display *number of results for this current page*, use

```
// Showing Page X of Y
print filter_var( absint( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->post_count ), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
```

For the *total amount of results*, use

```
print filter_var( absint( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->found_posts ), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
```

Answer (score 2):

display numbers of search results :

```
<?php global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->post_count; ?>
```

Comment: This is wrong. This is the number of posts, not the number of results.

Answer (score 0):

```
query_posts( $args );
global $wp_query;
print_r($wp_query->max_num_pages);
```

It help me.